# End of script output before headers: ea-php70

Tags: cpanel, phalcon, php-7

I'm running basic [phalconphp](https://phalconphp.com/en/) app on `php7.0`, and I got this error:

> "End of script output before headers: ea-php70"

I did many searches.

Additionally, whatever I choose `cgi` or `suPHP` as my PHP handler, the error is still there.

Any idea?

Comment: Is is an error related rather to improper handling of headers. What is the phalcon/php code you are trying to run? What is your phalcon version?

Comment: Do you have something in Github or the like we can look at?

Comment: This is my source code, actually, I use phalcon tool to generate it https://github.com/bnqtoan/phalcon-sample without any edit.

I used phalcon 3.2.

Comment: @bnqtoan I have the same problem. I am really confused. nothing works. have you managed to solve the problem?

this is my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319731/phalconphp-database-transactions-fail-on-server